# Having a non-optional argument follow an optional argument

Tags: ruby

On this code:

```
def plot(div_name = "", series , options = {} )
```

I'm getting a syntax error:

```
unexpected '=', expecting ')' (SyntaxError).
```

Why is that?
Assigning a default value to series solves the problem.

Comment: Please don't put your code in the title of the question in future. Code should be formatted in code tags appropriately: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Polynomial Be that as it may, I think your edit made the title 100% less helpful. I wouldn't even have clicked on a question titled "Why do I get a syntax error?". That title contains absolutely zero information about what the question is about. The original title told me everything I needed to know - missing code formatting or not.

Comment: @sepp2k - Apologies. I did edit it rather haphazardly. I've cleared it up to be more descriptive.

Comment: You're already using an options hash. Why not make series an option? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not allowed to have optional arguments followed by non-optional arguments followed by further optional arguments. If that were allowed, it would be ambiguous whether `plot(foo, bar)` should be `plot(foo, bar, {})` or `plot("", foo, bar)`.

Comment: Actually, the problem is having an optional argument followed by a non optional argument followed by an optional argument.

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed it is. Edited. (Non-optional arguments being allowed after optional arguments is new in 1.9, so I forgot about it).